# How to resolve AttributeError when using win32com.client api for opening MS word 2016 and access formFileds?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, win32com

I am working to automate report generation using python. In a word document, I need to update the Form Fields to complete the report generation.
On using `win32.com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch` api, I am not able to get the formFields from the word document.

Following is the script written:

I am getting following error:

```
    raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library.FormFields instance at 0x2217380698888>' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I tried to search for the help on how to get the FormFields present in the word document but could not find any proper documentation on the error that I am getting.

```py
word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible='False'
file = os.path.abspath(path)
d = word.Documents.Open(file)
d.FormFields[0].Result = reviewer
```

d.FormFields[0].Result should be a valid attribute.

on printing `d`, it is got to know that the object does not contain any FormFields at-all.

```
['CLSID', '__doc__', '__getattr__', '__init__', '__module__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '_dispobj_', 'coclass_interfaces', 'coclass_sources', 'default_interface', 'default_source']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `d` does not contain a Python object. It contains a thin Python wrapper around a COM object with a VBA interface.

Printing the `dir` of a Python object will show you its Python attributes. But `FormFields` is a VBA attribute of the COM object. Printing `dir(d)` will not show you the VBA attributes of the COM object.

But if there are forms in your document, you can see them like this:

```
>>> list (d.FormFields)
```

Look at your error message again. It says

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library.FormFields instance at 0x2217380698888>' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

That error message confirms that the VBA object `FormFields` is a valid attribute and is actually present because the message gives a memory location for its Python wrapper.

Your problem is elsewhere. I suspect that `FormFields` does not contain what you expect. There must be something in it because otherwise you would get an `IndexError`, but you can check this as follows:

```
>>> d.FormFields.Count
```

If you want to know what the attributes of the COM object are, then look in the VBA documentation.

As a side note, at this stage as a beginner, you really should not be investing time in learning Python 2. Support for Python 2 ceases at the end of this year. Some of us have no choice but to go on working in Python 2, but if you have a choice, switch, and soon.